# Images are not displayed in gridview in VS 2010 when retrieved from SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, gridview

I am trying to pull data from Images table which has ID, Name and the Image. Image is stored as byte I think, its of image datatype. However I couldn't see the image being displayed rather a small error icon. The screenshot of output is below. Could you please help correct it and display the image. I am newbie :(

I use this code. I want to tweak it to put the binary decoded image into 3rd gridview column named Image. I used ImageField. I dont use any templates as I see Item Templates are obsolete in VS 2010 editor.

```
  conn.Open();  
  // open the connection 
  SqlDataAdapter Sqa = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Images", conn);
  DataTable ds = new DataTable();
  Sqa.Fill(ds);   // fill the dataset 
  for (int i = 0; i < ds.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
      MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])ds.Rows[i]["Image"]);
  }
  GridView1.DataSource = ds; // give data to GridView
  GridView1.DataBind();
  conn.Close();
  GridView1.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way you suppose to display images. Currently you are giving gridview array of bytes as source for you image column. But gridview doesn't know that this array is an image. It would be much better if you will set datasource as array of links to images, and images itself would be requested from DB via separate requests. Http handler suits for this solution.

Take a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34084/Generic-Image-Handler-Using-IHttpHandler).

Comment: Hi Thank you. Oh my....Actually the link that you gave me looks greek and latin for me. I am a newbie :( Is there any quick solution now please, I need to give it ASAP :( Then I can go with best practices.

Comment: Unfortunately It won't work the way you made it. Handler is the easiest way. As http response have only one mime type, requests for images have to be made separately from request of page itself.

Comment: Johnny, thank you, but I am afraid, I didn't understand anything. I am new :( Is there a quick solution or small code for my situation please.

Comment: Sorry, that's the easiest I know. Give it couple hours to read about handlers and http image handlers, it's not so scary as seems to be.

Comment: Johnny, thank you so much, I finally achieved it through a very useful video. Now I understood, learned something :) Excited. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Your welcome. I'd recommend you Matthew MacDonald's book for asp.net programming.